# Repaying Loans vs Tzedakah

Tags: halacha, tzedakah-charity, borrowing

When one has to repay an interest-free loan to a Jewish lender, does that take precedence over giving tzedakah? If several payments must be made, can one thus expedite repayment by giving less to tzedakah?

Comment: Are you talking about less than 10% of income, or less than some higher amount?

Comment: @LiquidMetal less than 10%

Comment: ma'aser kesafim is not an explicit mitzvah in the Torah (it might be derabannan, it might be minhag yisroel, etc.) Repaying a loan is. Can you explain why you think a voluntary disbursement of charity takes place over your obligation to repay a loan? "If several payments must be made" - is this an agreed upon installment plan, or merely an admission that the borrower cannot pay all at once? If the latter, then most certainly. If the former, probably not - "Sorry, I need to pay off my entire mortgage before I start giving tzedaka."